# Can't put the list view under the text view

Tags: android, layout

This is my relative layout right now:
http://prntscr.com/d9yure

All I want is `deleteList` be under the `deleteUsersTxt`, but it doesn't let me. It only allows me to put it below invitation list. I have tried to add to it `android:layout_below="@+id/deleteUsersTxt"` but it just makes it dissapear.

This is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="meet.projectoklahoma.Activities.CreateEventActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/invitaionsList"

    android:layout_above="@id/deleteUsersTxt"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addUsersTxt" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/other"
    android:id="@+id/otherButton"
    android:onClick="setDate"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tomorrowButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/which_day"
    android:id="@+id/whichDayTxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eventNameTextBox"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tomorrow"
    android:id="@+id/tomorrowButton"
    android:onClick="tomorrow"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/todayButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/otherButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/otherButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="whichDay"
    android:id="@+id/dayTxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/whichDayTxt"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/whichDayTxt"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/whichDayTxt" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="date"
    android:id="@+id/dateTxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dayTxt"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dayTxt"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/dayTxt" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/which_time"
    android:id="@+id/timeTxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dateTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/choose_time"
    android:id="@+id/whichTimeBtn"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeTxt"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/todayButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/todayButton"
    android:onClick="setTime"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="whichTime"
    android:id="@+id/whichTimeTxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/add_users_to_event"
    android:id="@+id/addUsersTxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/whichTimeBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/today"
    android:id="@+id/todayButton"
    android:onClick="today"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dayTxt"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timeTxt"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/timeTxt" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/eventNameTextBox"
    android:text="שם האירוע"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="הסרת משתמשים מהאירוע:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/deleteUsersTxt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="131dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/cancelAndDeleteButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/delete_and_cancel"
    android:id="@+id/cancelAndDeleteButton"
    android:onClick="deleteEvent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="סבבה"
    android:id="@+id/SaveEventButton"
    android:onClick="editEvent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/deleteList"
    android:layout_below="@+id/invitaionsList"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Is there a minimum space for a list to be in?

Comment: I think your code works. But since you have a 131dp bottom-margin on `deleteUsersTxt`: You may be pushing the list outside of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is not something but everything goes wrong.

You can use LinearLayout (with vertical orientation) as your root layout to make it easy.

Then it will become more easy to understand for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping them inside of a LinearLayout and split them equally, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@id/deleteUsersTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addUsersTxt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/invitaionsList"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/deleteList"/>

</LinearLayout>
```